# How can I make Perl find my modules?

Tags: perl, http

```
sh-3.2# perl -v

This is perl, v5.8.9 built for darwin-2level
...


sh-3.2# perl 2348.pl 
Can't locate HTTP/Cookies.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9 /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9 /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/darwin-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9 .) at 2348.pl line 24.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at 2348.pl line 24.


sh-3.2# find / | grep -i "Cookies\.pm"
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0/HTTP/Cookies.pm
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.8.9/HTTP/Cookies.pm
/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.10/lib/HTTP/Cookies.pm
```

how to fix this? I understand I have to edit @INC but where is it? :)

Comment: You're on a MAC are you?

Comment: I think you mean "Mac", although that doesn't affect the answer really. It's the same answer that you would get otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, instead of MAC I should have said "#$!%".

Answer (score 5):

You installed [HTTP::Cookies](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Cookies) in a non-standard location. You can reinstall it with `cpan HTTP::Cookies` or `/opt/lang/bin/cpan HTTP::Cookies`.

Also see [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/cant-locate-foo-pm-in-inc-whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl)

Comment: Ether also recommends calling cpan with the full path because the shebang line should have the perl that installed cpan. Watch the output to see which directories you put it in: the CPAN.pm config might have specified something other than the default @INC.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should try

```
perl -I /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.8.9 -e'use HTTP::Cookies;'
```

Comment: same thing :(

sh-3.2# perl -I /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.8.9 -e'use HTTP::Cookies;'
sh-3.2# perl 2348.pl 
Can't locate HTTP/Cookies.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9 /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9 /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/darwin-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9 .) at 2348.pl line 24.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at 2348.pl line 24.
sh-3.2#

Comment: @yoble: He means that you should use the `I ...` argument when calling your script. The verbatim command he gave you will simply attempt to use the module and then exit (so if it errors, you can tell that the include path did not work). So do `perl -I/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.8.9  2348.pl`.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit `@INC` in your script:

```
BEGIN {
    unshift(@INC, '/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.8.9/');
    use HTTP::Cookies;
}
```

(Updated with suggestions from brian d foy)

Comment: You probably want that path at the front, and notice that he's running Perl 5.8.9. Although this will work since HTTP::Cookies is pure Perl, you might cause a binary incompatible module to load by looking in another version's library path.

Answer (score 0):

@INC is simply the array that references your includes, much like "path" does.

Try

```
do '/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.10/lib/HTTP/Cookies.pm'
```

and use HTTP::Cookies should work fine.

Edit: you can also find out what is in @INC

```
$myincludes = join(", ",@INC);
print $myincludes;
```

Comment: Yeah I kinda rushed this one.

Comment: sh-3.2# do '/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.10/lib/HTTP/Cookies.pm'

sh: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a custom-compiled Perl based in the '/opt/local' directory. Two things to investigate: where are you running Perl from? Is there another in `/usr/bin`? I'm guessing there's a system-installed one along side the libraries you found and the custom one you're using (in which case you may want to use the `cpan` utility to install the module you want into the custom location).

Comment: /opt/local is where macports installs its stuff (see http://macports.org); if `/opt/local/bin` isn't before `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`, call `/opt/lang/bin/cpan HTTP::Cookies`.

Comment: Oh, what a mess. Would have been helpful if the author pointed out he was using Apple software.

Comment: It doesn't matter that this is on Mac OS X. It's the same issue on any platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "edit" @INC.  It's locked into the binary.  (Yes, there are some windows installers that pad the value of @INC with 500 NULs so they can hot-patch the value, but let's not go there.)

So the only way to have a new value for @INC is to recompile the Perl distro.

Comment: This is simply false. I've written dozens of scripts with @INC altered.

Comment: No you haven't.  You haven't altered the @INC as it is bound in the binary.

Comment: To clarify: Randal is saying there's no way to "configure" the @INC path initially used by the `perl` executable.  It's built into the binary.  However, you can tell the executable that you want to look elsewhere at run-time, using command-line switches or Perl code particular to that execution.  But you'll have to do this each time you run your code, as those techniques last only for that invocation.