# Why can't XML::Schematron::XPath find XML::XPath?

Tags: perl, module, schematron

After installing the XML::Schematron::XPath module from CPAN I am getting the "Can't locate XML/XPath.pm in @INC) message.

```
]$sudo ls /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/XML/
ESISParser.pm  Filter  Handler  Parser  PatAct  Perl2SAX.pm  SAX2Perl.pm  Schematron Schematron.pm  Validator
```

There is the Schematron directory, and inside of it is XPath.pm.

Why is it looking for XML/XPath.pm when I clearly state in my perl script:

```
use XML::Schematron::XPath;
```

@INC:
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0 
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .

Comment: please post the output of print "@INC\n";

Comment: How did you install XML::Schematron::XPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you install XML::XPath

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`XML::Path`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Path) indirectly, such as inside `XML::Schematron::XPath`. If you installed `XML::Schematron::XPath` via CPAN it should have brought in the dependencies automatically, but at any rate you can install your dependencies now.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/cant-locate-foo-pm-in-inc-whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl) for more about installing a Perl module via CPAN.

Comment: Yeah, thats why I posted this question and was confused.. I used cpan to install it and I guess it missed depends for what ever reason.