# Why does my Perl program complain "Can't locate URI.pm in @INC"?

Tags: perl, installation, module

I'm new to Perl. I get the following error when I run a script:

```
Can't locate URI.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/packages/perl_remote/5.6.1/lib/5.6.1/i86pc-solaris /usr/local/packages/perl_remote/5.6.1/lib/5.6.1 /usr/local/packages/perl_remote/5.6.1/lib/site_perl/5.6.1/i86pc-solaris /usr/local/packages/perl_remote/5.6.1/lib/site_perl/5.6.1 /usr/local/packages/perl_remote/5.6.1/lib/site_perl .) at (eval 2) line 3.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/packages/perl_remote/5.6.1/lib/site_perl/5.6.1/HTTP/Request.pm line 3.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/packages/perl_remote/5.6.1/lib/site_perl/5.6.1/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/packages/perl_remote/5.6.1/lib/site_perl/5.6.1/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/packages/perl_remote/5.6.1/lib/site_perl/5.6.1/LWP/Simple.pm line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/packages/perl_remote/5.6.1/lib/site_perl/5.6.1/LWP/Simple.pm line 26.
Compilation failed in require at txotf_0_install.pl line 35.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at txotf_0_install.pl line 35.
```

What could be the possible reasons of this and how do I get the script to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can often find the answers by searching for key words from the error message. In this case, searching SO just for "locate" quickly leads you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/cant-locate-foo-pm-in-inc-whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Possibly you do not have `URI` installed. It might not be saved anywhere on your machine, or it might be "installed" in a location.

  - If it's just not installed, then you need to install it from CPAN.
  - If you have it saved to your machine, you just need to let the system know where to get it.

If you have to install it from CPAN, you likely need administrator privileges to put it in the listed directories. But CPAN will allow you to install it to a user directory, so you can still install it.

So if you can't install the module in the directories listed in `@INC`, then there are the various ways.

1. Perl 5 reads a environment variable called `PERL5LIB`. Any directory in that "array" will be *prepended* to `@INC`. So anything in the directory structure of `$ENV{PERL5LIB}` will be preferred to any system directory. (see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERLLIB))
2. Another way you can do this is per *script*. The `use lib` pragma also inserts specified directories into `@INC`. (see [lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html))

   ```
   use lib '/path/to/URI/module';
   use URI;
   ```
3. The final way, you can do it per *run*. You can run perl with the `-I` switch on the command line `perl -I/path/to/URI/module -e 1` (see [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html))

Answer (score 7):

The nonstandard paths in `@INC` (e.g. `/usr/local/packages`, `perl_remote` etc) indicate to me that this is a custom `perl` installed for a specific purpose probably with reduced functionality to prevent mischief.

***Ask the sysadmin.***

Answer (score 1):

The array @INC contains the list of places to look for Perl scripts to be evaluated. Your script will not run because it is not in the @INC list. Either:

1. Put the script in one of the @INC locations; or
2. Add the location of the file to the $PATH environmental variable; or
3. Specify the full path of the script when you are calling it.

Comment: The problem can also be that the URI.pm module is not installed (liburi-perl package on my ubuntu, but i dont know the module's name on solaris)

Comment: Well, not installed or installed in a directory not in @INC.

Answer (score 0):

This is not to say that any of the other answers aren't all good advice (they very likely address your issue), but I ran into a similar issue which had me puzzled for a couple hours.  While I'm not sure this addresses the OP's problem, perhaps someone stumbling across this in the future will save themselves some time troubleshooting...

I found on a new CentOS server that despite @INC reporting the path to my custom libraries included and despite all file and directory permissions being set correctly mod_perl was still bailing out with a message that it "Can't locate" the modules in question.  This was doubly puzzling because similar scripts with the same "use lib" statement that Apache's PerlRequire was using were able to run without issue.

The culprit turned out to be SELinux, and disabling it took care of this immediately.  More details on the /var/log/messages info that led me to this as well as other general gripes can be found [here](http://studyofcrying.blogspot.com/2011/03/apache-2-modperl-htmlmason-use-lib-and.html).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just copied the perl folder to another machine and added path to bin folder to PATH environment variable. In order to fix the issue, I had to run the proper installation of ActivePerl which at the end setup all the environment properly for perl.