# Why do I get this module error: "Can't locate Error.pm in @INC"?

Tags: perl, module

I tried running:

```
perl -e "use Error;"
```

from cmd in windows 7.  (active perl 5.12 installed on system) and I am getting the error

> Can't locate Error.pm in @INC (@INC
>   contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib
>   C:/Perl64/lib )

I manually searched and found `Error.pm` in `C:/Perl64/lib/CPANPLUS`.

Does anyone have an idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Sounds like your cpanplus was misconfigured, so it installed libraries in the wrong place.

Comment: Answerers on crack again today; the question clearly asks about [Error](http://p3rl.org/Error) and everyone talks about the irrelevant [CPANPLUS::Error](http://p3rl.org/CPANPLUS::Error). chuck, you just have to install this missing module before you can use it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module

Answer (score 4):

You have to install the module [Error](http://p3rl.org/Error) that can be found on CPAN.
But be aware of this warning:

> Using the "Error" module is no longer recommended due to the black-magical
>   nature of its syntactic sugar, which often tends to break. Its maintainers
>   have stopped actively writing code that uses it, and discourage people from
>   doing so. See the "SEE ALSO" section below for better recommendations.

Comment: To do this, run `sudo cpan Error`

Comment: @AlastairIrvine Never do `sudo cpan`.

Answer (score 1):

lib/CPANPLUS/Error.pm is a core "CPANPLUS::Error" module. It is used by CPANPLUS. If you want to use non-core "Error" module, you need to install it. Do "ppm install Error". Also, you can use similar modules Try::Tiny and TryCatch. They are non-core too, so you also would need to install them.

Comment: Note, this only works with ActivePerl, NOT for Strawberry Perl. On Strawberry Perl you need to use `cpan`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on CentOS 7.3, and I have git-1.8.3.1-23 and perl-Error-0.17014-1 rpm packages installed and still got this error. I didn't want to mess with installing perl modules via CPAN. I figured out the path where perl-Error is installed (`rpm -ql perl-Error`) and am now running git commands like so:

```
PERL5LIB="/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8" git add -p someFile.sh
```

This works fine for me. Note that the path may be different for you.

Answer (score 0):

On Centos 8, you can installing `perl-Error` to get this module:

```
sudo dnf install perl-Error
```

Answer (score -2):

you could set PERL5LIB to prepend a directory to @INC

```
PERL5LIB="C:/Perl64/lib/CPANPLUS"
```

I forget how to set env variables permanently in windows (or if this is even the right syntax for the shell.)

also to see your @INC perl -V

Comment: This answer is wrong and does not work. Follow the instructions of the first answer.