# Perl getting "can't locate error" trying to use IO::prompt

Tags: perl

```
C:\sample\ss>perl dd_tsys.pl
Can't locate IO/prompt.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/strawberry/perl/lib C:/stra
wberry/perl/site/lib C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib .) at dd_tsys.pl line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at dd_tsys.pl line 8.
```

I installed the io::pack, but when I try to use the IO::prompt, it saying the above error,

Here are my installation steps I followed, [check it out](http://happylife.in/node/6).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5262957#5263741 for the first part of the story.

Comment: The [x-ref](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5262957) from @daxim mentions '[IO::Prompt does not work on Windows](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/IO-Prompt#2957)' which may be an additional problem, even once the module compiles on Windows (which, apparently, it sometimes does).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl is case-sensitive; the module is [IO::Prompt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aPrompt).

Additionally, your build log shows:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t\01.dependencies.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 2 Failed: 2)
Failed tests: 1-2
Non-zero exit status: 2
Files=4, Tests=3, 1 wallclock secs ( 0.06 usr + 0.03 sys = 0.09 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/4 test programs. 2/3 subtests failed.
DCONWAY/IO-Prompt-0.997001.tar.gz
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe ./Build test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
reports DCONWAY/IO-Prompt-0.997001.tar.gz
Running Build install
make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
DCONWAY/IO-Prompt-0.997001.tar.gz : make_test NO
```

So, the module was not installed, which is the rest of the reason it is not found.