# Amazon SES setup problems

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services

I'm running into an unexpected amount of difficulty trying to use ses-verify-email-address. I am using Ubuntu Hardy on AWS with Perl 5.8.8.

After copying the Perl scripts and creating a key file, I got a "command not found" error. Then I installed the files mentioned in the SES README - Digest::SHA, URI::Escape, Bundle::LWP, MIME::Base64, Crypt::SSLeay and XML::LibXML. It's not obvious that these installed correctly and now when I run ses-verify-email-address.pl, I get the message "LWP will support https URLs if the LWP::Protocol::https module is installed."

I've been using Python and know nothing about Perl.

Comment: I am getting this same problem, rather frustrating that Amazon makes use jump through these hoops to test the SES service, I still haven't found a post anywhere that answers this issue

Comment: What eventually worked for me was this. After each report from the Amazon Perl script that it was missing something, I went to [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) and searched for it. Then copied and extracted the tar. Then did 1. perl makefile.PL, 2. make, 3. make test, 4. make install.

Answer (score 3):

Install [`LWP::Protocol::https`](http://p3rl.org/LWP::Protocol::https).

See [*What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module) from the [SO Perl FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq), [*How to install CPAN modules*](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) on CPAN, and [perlmodinstall](http://p3rl.org/modinstall) in the Perl documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I installed that but get a report at the end that 2/2 test failed. ses-verify-email-address still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. It turned out not to be LWP::Protocol::https, but one of its dependencies. Try running `perl -MLWP::Protocol::https -e 1` ([source](http://www.perlhowto.com/check_if_a_module_is_installed)) to see if you get any error messages. That just tells perl to include that module and then return the value `1`, so there's no harm in running the command. If you get nothing in return that means the module is installed correctly. I suspect you'll get an error message. In my case I was missing Net::SSL, so running `perl -MNet::SSL -e 1` also gave an error message.