# Perl Module installation?

Tags: perl

How do you install a perl module that requires compilation of C code? I do know the general installation using PPM and CPAN. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: by refering to PPM I suppose you're using Active State Perl - probably on Windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ActiveState Perl](http://www.perl.com/pub/2011/08/using-cpan-on-win32-activeperl.html) and [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) are distributions that already comes with all necessary parts. (On outdated version of ActiveState Perl, you had to  [install and set up the compiler toolchain](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/10/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl) yourself.)

Then, simply install modules as per the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [**What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)