# Perl Script - Can't locate Net/SSH/Perl.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I am trying to get a Perl script running which was simply copied from one Windows 2003 x64 to another Windows machine of the same type.

I installed ActivePerl and I receive following error:

```
F:\Supportsaves\Scripts\Supportsave_Script>Can't locate Net/SSH/Perl.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at F:\Supportsaves\Scripts\switches_supportsave.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at F:\Supportsaves\Scripts\switches_supportsave.pl line 11.
```

I have searched and possibly the [Net::SSH::Perl](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl) is missing, but I don't get it installed (after setting the proxy) I get

```
F:\Supportsaves\Scripts\Supportsave_Script>ppm install Net-SSH-Perl
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides Net-SSH-Perl
```

When using ppm I can't find this module in GUI.

CPAN creates other errors.

Any help is appreciated.

---

```
 Result after installing Net::SSH::Perl in Strawberry, CPAN   Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/03-packet.t    (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
Non-zero exit status: 255
Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 10 tests but ran 0.
Files=12, Tests=106,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr +  0.03 sys =  0.12 CPU)
Result: FAIL`

Failed 1/12 test programs. 0/106 subtests failed.
dmake.EXE:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
TURNSTEP/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34.tar.gz
2 dependencies missing (Math::Pari,Crypt::RSA); additionally test harness failed`

C:\Perl\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
reports TURNSTEP/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34.tar.gz
Running make install
make test had returned bad status, won't install without force`

`F:\Supportsaves\Scripts\Supportsave_Script>`

-----------------

Installing in Active Perl with CPAN Net::SSH::Perl does partly work well, there are   
missing dependencies, which can't be installed either...

Result: PASS
TURNSTEP/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34.tar.gz
Tests succeeded but 7 dependencies missin  
(Crypt::IDEA,Math::Pari,Crypt::DSA,Convert::PEM,String::CRC32,Math::GMP,Crypt 
::RSA)
TURNSTEP/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34.tar.gz
[dependencies] -- NA
Running make install
make test had returned bad status, won't install without force`

`F:\Supportsaves\Scripts\Supportsave_Script>`

 Crypt::IDEA fails ...
 C:\Perl\site\lib\auto\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32  
 \bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lbufferoverflowU
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'blib\arch\auto\Crypt\IDEA\IDEA.dll'
 DPARIS/Crypt-IDEA-1.08.tar.gz
 C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
 CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.35)
 Running make test
 Can't test without successful make
 Running make install
 Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible `
```

Comment: What "other errors" does CPAN create?

Comment: It's in CPAN as far as I can tell...  [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH-Perl/)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689945/how-do-we-configure-ssh-using-perl-in-windows



regards,

Comment: *ActivePerl* is generally very bad at installing modules from CPAN that contain C (XS) files needing compilation. The best way to go is to use ppm, or to migrate to *Strawberry Perl*.

Comment: Yes, either Strawberry Perl (or [DWIMPerl](http://dwimperl.com/)) is far superior to ActivePerl.

Comment: Borodin's and Jack Maney's claim is outdated. ActivePerl is no worse than other popular Windows distributions since [it pulls in a MinGW based toolchain](http://www.perl.com/pub/2011/08/using-cpan-on-win32-activeperl.html) when needed. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5620297/46395

Comment: I still have yet to successfully run mod_perl on strawberry perl. Once they get that together I'll be using strawberry as well!

Comment: Thanks for your hints but unfortunately I don't get it running. I reinstalled Active Perl, installed Strawberry and now active Perl again.                                                                 Result after isnstalling Net::SSH::Perl in Strawberry, CPAN

Comment: if anyone has additional ideas please let me know

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the `Net::SSH::Perl` module is only in the *Bribes* ppm repository at

```
http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/
```

If you add that to your ppm's list of repositories it should install it correctly.

Comment: I have added this repository, it shows somehow 0 pkgs and I can 't find Net::SSH::Perl

Answer (score 4):

Try this, this may works:

```
ppm install http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/Net-SSH2.ppd
ppm install http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/Net-SSH-Perl.ppd
```

regards,

Comment: It can't find the right code....                                  F:\Supportsaves\Scripts\Supportsave_Script>ppm install http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/Net-SSH2.ppd
ppm install failed: The PPD does not provide code to install for this platform

Comment: Maybe this helps you. http://search.cpan.org/~csjewell/Perl-Dist-Strawberry-2.5001/script/perldist_strawberry This script downloads and builds a full CPAN mirror for Strawberry perl. After this you could copy onl the needed module.