# SGML::Parser::OpenSP doesn't work when installing local W3C validator on Windows

Tags: perl, xampp

I am trying to configure a local W3C validator on my XAMPP server in Windows. I have copied the validator to XAMPP. When I try to run validator/htdocs/index.html it's giving  some error like

> Can't locate loadable object for module SGML::Parser::OpenSP in @INC (@INC contains: D:/Web/xampp/perl/site/lib/

But I have my OpenSP.pm (and it's the correct version 0.991) in D:\Web\xampp\perl\site\lib\SGML\Parser. The procedure I am following to add new .pm file is

1. download the tar.gz file
2. unzip it using 7z
3. just copy the .pm files from folder to D:\Web\xampp\perl\site\lib\

Is this the right way? Because it's not showing any errors for many other packages which I have added in similar manner.

How I can solve this error?

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [*What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Answer (score 1):

I quickly looked into [SGML::Parser::OpenSP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SGML%3a%3aParser%3a%3aOpenSP) ... the module is using XS, so it requires C compilation to install properly. Copying plain files will work only with pure-perl modules and only if you satisfy all its dependencies.

However I don't know perl included in xampp, so difficult to advice how to proceed with installation.

Comment: To expand on this a little — CPAN packages include installers, bypassing the installer only works if you manually do everything that the installer is designed to do. Whatever Perl distribution you are using should have a means to install CPAN modules. The XAMPP documentation is rather light on the subject though (so I'd be tempted to dump it and install Strawberry Perl and Apache)

Comment: i am using xampp for other works. so i cant replace it. i tried to install SGML-Parser-OpenSP-0.991.tar.gz using cygwin. when i try doing >> perl Makefile.PL its giving some error as Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lm
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lstdc++ , Note (probably harmless): No library found for -losp

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the SGML-Parser-OpenSP cpan module instead of just unzipping the archive and copying files. But unfortunately until now April 2012, I have never found anyone who has succeeded in installing SGML-Parser-OpenSP 0.994 on windows. I have been trying the installation for the last 2 weeks. But I didn't succeed, yet. Is there anyone who succeeds in installing SGML-Parser-OpenSP 0.994 on windows? Please let me contact him or her. I want to hear his or her advices. My contact address yooseok@naver.com.