# Trying to install perl's Catalyst framework on debian 6. - Can't use an undefined value as a HASH

Tags: perl, installation, catalyst

```
[14:27: /mnt/mydocuments/git_working_dir/cat_example$] catalyst.pl hello_world
Couldn't load class (Catalyst::Exception::Basic) because: Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at /usr/lib/perl5/MooseX/Role/WithOverloading/Meta/Role/Application.pm line 45.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 117.
 at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 123
    Class::MOP::__ANON__('Can\'t use an undefined value as a HASH reference at /usr/lib...') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Try/Tiny.pm line 100
    Try::Tiny::try('CODE(0x29021c8)', 'Try::Tiny::Catch=REF(0x28fca88)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 128
    Class::MOP::load_first_existing_class('Catalyst::Exception::Basic') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Class/MOP.pm line 140
    Class::MOP::load_class('Catalyst::Exception::Basic', undef) called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Util.pm line 126
    Moose::Util::_apply_all_roles('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x2b63fe0)', undef, 'Catalyst::Exception::Basic') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Util.pm line 93
    Moose::Util::apply_all_roles('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x2b63fe0)', 'Catalyst::Exception::Basic') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose.pm line 60
    Moose::with('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x2b63fe0)', 'Catalyst::Exception::Basic') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Moose/Exporter.pm line 356
    Moose::with('Catalyst::Exception::Basic') called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Exception.pm line 50
    require Catalyst/Exception.pm called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Utils.pm line 4
    Catalyst::Utils::BEGIN() called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Exception.pm line 0
    eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Exception.pm line 0
    require Catalyst/Utils.pm called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Helper.pm line 12
    Catalyst::Helper::BEGIN() called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Exception.pm line 0
    eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Exception.pm line 0
    require Catalyst/Helper.pm called at /usr/bin/catalyst.pl line 26
    main::BEGIN() called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Exception.pm line 0
    eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Exception.pm line 0
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Utils.pm line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Utils.pm line 4.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Helper.pm line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Catalyst/Helper.pm line 12.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/catalyst.pl line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/catalyst.pl line 26.
[14:27: /mnt/mydocuments/git_working_dir/cat_example$]
```

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as root

```
cpan Catalyst::Runtime
cpan Package::Stash
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe, how you tried to install?

There is many ways, i'd like to stick to package manager, so just:

`sudo apt-get install libcatalyst-perl`

Update:
Your problem is certainly in mixed use of CPAN and Debian packages. You must get rid of one and you get it working.

Comment: Yeah this is my mistake. This is what *doesn't* work. Basically catalyst relies on third party modules to make it work from cpan and since cpan is outside the Debian repository, Catalyst is broken on a fresh install.

Comment: @Philluminati: this can't be the reason. In Debian repository are all Catalyst dependencies too. I suppose there may be some conflict between CPAN and Debian repository. Problems may rise when tried to use catalyst from both... I tried Catalyst from repository and it worked fine.