# perl how to install all dependencies that list in the text file?

Tags: perl, dependencies, cpan

I have a file which has a list of library I need for a perl script. How to tell the perl to automatically install all of them ?

The file I have it something like this.

dependencies.txt

> Memoize
>   Carp
>   Time::Hires

Comment: I hope that you meant `Time::Hires` (two colons).

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Comment: @cjm, I hope that you meant [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::HiRes) (camel case HiRes). :P

Comment: @Ashley, yes, I just noticed the missing colon, I didn't validate the module name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to [install cpanm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App%3a%3acpanminus#INSTALLATION) and then type:

```
cpanm <dependencies.txt
```