# Whats does the Perl error "Can't locate Net/SSH/Perl.pm" mean?

Tags: perl, ssh

I am running a perl script that uses SSH, but it prints the following error:

> Can't locate Net/SSH/Perl.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl
>   /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5
>   /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10
>   /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at newone.pl line 3. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at newone.pl line 3.

Perl can't seem to locate Net/SSH/Perl.pm.  Why can't it find it and how do I install it?

Answer (score 8):

Your code is fine, although I haven't checked it as the error is due to a missing perl module.

[What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Comment: Or `cpan install Net::SSH`, or `perl -MCPAN -we 'install "Net::SSH"'`, or `ppm install Net::SSH` if you're on Windows.

Comment: @PedroSilva: Net::SSH and Net::SSH::Perl are not the same module.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install and/or include the appropriate SSH library for perl. You can install it using this command:

`cpan install Net::SSH::Perl`

Comment: I had to include the `-f` flag: `cpan -f install Net::SSH::Perl` to force the command since there were test errors on my machine.  Be prepared to wait 10 minutes for this command to complete.