# Perl module installation - Unix

Tags: perl

I would like to know about the perl module installations in unix.
Can anyone please explain the steps?

Comment: See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html

Comment: You are supposed to show some level of research effort before posting a question.

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from using the [`cpan`](https://metacpan.org/module/cpan) client, there is another client named [`cpanm` (cpanminus)](https://metacpan.org/module/cpanm) which is gaining in popularity.

### Installing `cpanm`

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --self-upgrade
```

Or:

```
wget -O - http://cpanmin.us | perl - --self-upgrade
```

### Installing modules with `cpanm`

```
cpanm Name::of::Module
```

Use the `-S` flag for `sudo`. [Read more about `cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/module/cpanm).

Answer (score 4):

If only there was [a manual page about this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html) which came as part of the standard Perl installation.

Answer (score 1):

In these links, [How to install CPAN modules](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) and [How To Install Perl Modules Manually and Using CPAN command](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/how-to-install-perl-modules-manually-and-using-cpan-command/), you may find the all the information that you need. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Perl module manually using CPAN (cf. [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html) mentioned by [davorg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/davorg) or [bacchus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/708312/bacchus))
or try to find out in the packages if you are using unix systems with packages management.

For example to install the module Net::Twitter you can do :

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Net::Twitter'
```

or for example if you are on a Debian Squeeze :

```
aptitude install libnet-twitter-perl
```

Sometime the module you are looking for may be packaged