# How to install DFA::Simple or DFA::Command Perl module in my active perl for windows XP

Tags: perl, state-machine

i am using active perl 5.12 for 32 bit windows XP laptop.i want to install DFA::Simple or DFA::Command module to create a finite state machine.i tried installing from ppm repositories using ppm install [ppmx file] but it didn't install properly.please suggest me any other method which would be better to insrall or any other perl module which can be used to crate a simple state machine.

Comment: Are DFA::Simple and DFA::Command on CPAN?

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Answer (score 1):

Download it. Then do from command prompt:

```
perl Makefile.pl.
dmake test
dmake install
```

DFA::Simple module was deleted from CPAN, but you should be able to find it on [backpan](http://backpan.perl.org/authors/id/R/RA/RANDYM/).

P.S. You can download dmake on CPAN. You may use nmake instead of dmake.

Answer (score 0):

DFA::Simple is on github at https://github.com/gitpan/DFA-Simple.