# How to install pp (PAR Packager)?

Tags: perl, par, perl-packager

I have to create an exe from a Perl script. I installed

```
ActivePerl-5.14.2.1402-MSWin32-x86-295342.msi
```

How do I install [pp](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.010/lib/pp.pm)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until the issue with `1.010` is fixed, do the following:

1. Go to http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-Packer/
2. From the "Other releases" drop down list, select `PAR-Packer-1.009` and download it
3. Decompress the archive, preserving directory structure
4. Run `perl Makefile.PL`
5. Install all the missing prerequisites by hand using `ppm`. E.g., `ppm install Module::ScanDeps` etc
6. Install MingW: `ppm install MingW`
7. `dmake`, then `dmake test`, then `dmake install`

Later, you can remove `PAR::Packer` from the site area using the `ppm` GUI and install the fixed version.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is a relatively old question, but for the sake of others, here is a solution that worked for me using pp ([Par Packager](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.024/lib/pp.pm)):

1. Install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html) for windows (I installed strawberry-perl-5.16.3.1-64bit.msi)

   - I used 5.16.3.1 because I wanted to try out perl2exe as well, while I'm at it (perl2exe at the time supported only up to 5.16.3 version of perl)
2. Once installed, open Strawberry Perl Tools (e.g. through start menu -> All programs -> Strawberry Perl -> Tools), and invoke CPAN Client
3. In the client console that opens, type:

   - `get pp`
   - `install pp`
4. Once installation is complete, you can simply run:

   - `c:\strawberry\perl\site\bin\pp.bat -o myScript.exe myScript.pl`
   - Which will produce a *myScript.exe* which is a standalone executable (no **external** perl interpreter is needed)

**Note:** You can use the *-d* command line switch in order to reduce the size of the executable. This will not include perl interpreter code inside the executable, reducing the size of the executable, however you will need to provide *perl5x.dll* in the same directory as your executable, or include it on the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

This is a Perl module called [PAR::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.010/lib/pp.pm), so it can be installed as any Perl module with CPAN. Unfortunately, you're using ActivePerl which isn't quite compatible with CPAN. Instead, you can see if use ActiveState's [Perl Package Manager](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.12/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html) to install this module.

If the module isn't available via the Perl Package Manger, you can try installing with the CPAN command line utility. Open up a Console Window (Start->Accessories->Command Prompt) and type in `cpan` and press `<ENTER>`. Newer versions of ActiveState should [automatically](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/10/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl) install the required compilers, etc. when you first start to use CPAN.

I prefer [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com) for Windows because it's more compatible with CPAN. However, ActivePerl has a lot of the Win32 modules already installed. Plus, it comes with the Perl Package Manager which is nice.

**WARNING**: ActiveState installs a lot of these Perl scripts not in `C:\Perl\bin`, but in `C:\Perl\Site\bin` which means you have to make sure that directory is in your path too.

Comment: @JackManey - If the poster was asking which version of Perl to use, I would advocate Strawberry over ASP, but ASP is already installed. However, ActiveState can use CPAN for module installation, and will install MinGW if required. I haven't found a module ASP won't install although people tell me there are a few.

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.010, the software cannot be automatically packaged, see the report at [Trouchelle's repo](http://trouchelle.com/perl/ppmrepview.pl?id=61525&v=14).

Install CPAN using PPM, then continue as per the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Answer (score 1):

```
ppm install MinGW
cpanp i Win32::Exe PAR::Packer
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers,
You can use cpan to install the PAR::Packer.
From your windows command prompt use the command: cpan install PAR::Packer.
Note: I have Strawberry perl installed.
cpan installs the modules and the dependencies as well.

Comment: Without instruction with what one with "PAR::Packer or Strawberry Perl this isn't a very helpful answer.