# PERL - installing PAR::Packer with ppm

Tags: perl, perl-module

When I want to install PAR_Packer using `ppm install PAR-Packer` I face with the error:

`ppm install failed: Cant't find any package that provides PAR-Packer`.

Windows 8.1 x64

**Perl**: ActivePerl-5.16.3.1603-MSWin32-x86-296746

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8055269/223226

Comment: @mpapec : I tried that but `cpan` needs `MinGW` and also I got the same error for installing `MinGW` with `ppm install MinGW`

Comment: I'm afraid you're stuck if you want to stay with ActivePerl.

Comment: @mpapec you're right. I had better install Strawberry Perl.

Comment: Can you install anything using ppm?

Comment: @SlavenRezic yes I could but I removed activePerl and installed strawberry and the problem was resolved