# Why can't I install the Perl PAR::Packer module?

Tags: perl

I am trying to convert my perl scripts into executable files for Windows. The executable file should include all modules, too.

I am trying to install PAR Packer using ppm but I get an error message :

```
"ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides PAR::Packer"
```

code:

```
 ppm install PAR::Packer
```

How to make pp work which is present in PAR::Packer? 
Else, is there any other module / free software to convert Perl to exe?

Comment: That seems like a very short error message.  Are you pasting in the entire error message, or just retyping a portion of it?

Comment: edited my error message. its complete now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that there is no PPM package for PAR::Packer.

You're using ActivePerl which makes its own PPM packages which are a subset of the full range of CPAN modules available.

See this answer for more: [How to install pp (PAR Packager)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055063/how-to-install-pp-par-packager)

Answer (score 1):

I found that using CPAN alone was not enough to get PAR::Packer installed on my version of Perl (Perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread) on Windows 7. To get the module installed I first had to install Win32::Exe via the ActiveState PPM, then switch and install the PAR::Packer module with CPAN.

Comment: yes true. i had to install Win32::Exe too