# Extract text from HTML - Perl using HTML::TreeBuilder

Tags: html, perl, html-content-extraction, text-extraction, htmlcleaner

I'm trying to access the .html files and extract the text in `<p>` tags. Logically, my code below should work. By using the HTML::TreeBuilder. I parse the html then extract text in `<p>` using find_by_attribute("p"). But my script came out with empty directories. Did i leave out anything?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use HTML::TreeBuilder 3;
use FileHandle;

my @task = ('ar','cn','en','id','vn');

foreach my $lang (@task) {
mkdir "./extract_$lang", 0777 unless -d "./extract_$lang";
opendir (my $dir, "./$lang/") or die "$!";
my @files = grep (/\.html/,readdir ($dir));
closedir ($dir);

foreach my $file (@files) {
    open (my $fh, '<', "./$lang/$file") or die "$!";
    my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
    $root->parse_file("./$lang/$file");
    my @all_p = $root->find_by_attribute("p");
    foreach my $p (@all_p) {
        my $ptag = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content ($p->as_HTML);
        my $filewrite = substr($file, 0, -5); 
        open (my $outwrite, '>>', "extract_$lang/$filewrite.txt") or die $!;
        print $outwrite $ptag->as_text . "\n";  
        my $pcontents = $ptag->as_text;
        print $pcontents . "\n";
        close (outwrite);
    }
close (FH);
}
}
```

My .html files are the plain text htmls from .asp websites e.g. http://www.singaporemedicine.com/vn/hcp/med_evac_mtas.asp

My .html files are saved in:

```
./ar/*
./cn/*
./en/*
./id/*
./vn/*
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing [element with attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/about.html#h-1.2.1). The program can be written much more concisely:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strictures;
use File::Glob qw(bsd_glob);
use Path::Class qw(file);
use URI::file qw();
use Web::Query qw(wq);
use autodie qw(:all);

foreach my $lang (qw(ar cn en id vn)) {
    mkdir "./extract_$lang", 0777 unless -d "./extract_$lang";
    foreach my $file (bsd_glob "./$lang/*.html") {
        my $basename = file($file)->basename;
        $basename =~ s/[.]html$/.txt/;
        open my $out, '>>:encoding(UTF-8)', "./extract_$lang/$basename";
        $out->say($_) for wq(URI::file->new_abs($file))->find('p')->text;
        close $out;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a warning message `Wide character in print at extract.pl line 24.` Is there a limitation to the TreeBuilder? It still prints out even though perl gives the warning, right?

Comment: You must specify the text output encoding. Compare how I open the output file with how you do it. Learn about the topic of encoding in Perl at http://p3rl.org/UNI

Comment: I tried with your code but i got a compilation error at `use strictures`, i'm getting errors at the other `use` attributes too. Do i need to install a new perl to make them work?

Comment: Error: `Can't locate strictures.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.12.4 /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.12 /usr/share/perl/5.12 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at extract-daxim.pl line 3.`

Comment: Replace `use strictures;` with `use strict; use warnings;` Or install the `strictures` distribution from CPAN.

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/65865)

Comment: ah now i get it! install CPAN on my machine.

Comment: @daxim, i'm still getting an error where it says `Bareword found where operator expected at extract-daxim.pl line 14, near "s/[.]html$/.txt/r" ` is it the tilde ~?

Comment: i don't understand this part of the code ` . file($file)->basename =~ s/[.]html$/.txt/r;` the file and basename has no `my` or `$`, are they  from the Path::Class and File::Glob ??

Comment: 2er0, [the `r` modifier is available only in Perl 5.13.2 or better](http://p3rl.org/perl5132delta#Non-destructive-substitution). Either install an additional stable Perl 5.14.x ([perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl) makes this easy), or use the revised version of the code above that works around the lack of `r`. — `file` is an exported function, `basename` is a method. Both are documented in [Path::Class::File](http://p3rl.org/Path::Class::File). Please read an intermediate level Perl teaching book to understand the underlying concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Use `find_by_tag_name` to search for tag names, not `find_by_attribute`.

Answer (score 3):

You want `find_by_tag_name`, not `find_by_attribute`:

```
my @all_p = $root->find_by_tag_name("p");
```

From the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aElement):

> $h->find_by_tag_name('tag', ...)
>
> In list context, returns a list of elements at or under $h that have
>   any of the specified tag names. In scalar context, returns the first
>   (in pre-order traversal of the tree) such element found, or undef if
>   none.

Comment: does it mean if the <p> tag is embedded, i might need to rerun the loop again? e.g. `<p>...<p>...<\p>...<\p>`

Comment: @2er0 this method will return all `p` elements at once. You can use it on the resulting elements in turn to find nested `p`s.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Mojo::DOM which lets you use CSS selectors.