# Cygwin Perl installation missing CPAN

Tags: perl, cygwin, cpan, buildroot

I'm using the [Buildroot](http://buildroot.org/) makefiles on Cygwin to make some basic Linux systems, which requires several Perl modules.
CPAN does not seem to have installed with Perl, so I can't install any modules them without a lot of work (I know basically nothing about Perl)
How can I get CPAN working? Thanks

Thought I'd return to this in case anyone comes back in the future:
It seems to be unsupported and impossible to use Buildroot on Cygwin, so don't bother unless you really think you can make it work. If you do make it work please let me know :)

[image: Output]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208126/discussion-between-arraysstartat1-and-ikegami).

Comment: You can just type `cpan Module::Name` to install stuff. Not that it helps `cpan` not even being there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, we came to find:

```
$ cygcheck -c perl_base
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
perl_base            5.30.1-1       OK

$ cygcheck -c perl
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
perl                 5.26.3-2       OK
```

At some point, the `perl_base` package (the essential files) were updated. `perl_base` doesn't depend on `perl` (the rest of core perl), so the `perl` package wasn't updated at that time.

Those two packages need to be upgraded in step. The discrepancies in the versions is causing the problem. Upgrading the `perl` package to match fixed the problem.