# Encrypt in PHP, Decrypt in Perl

Tags: php, perl, encryption

```
$key = "12345678876543211234567887654321";
$iv = "1234567887654321";
$plaindata = "String to be encrypted.";

$enc = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaindata, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));

echo($enc);
```

Output:

```
EIZDQJWOIepUeNjFL2wl3RYA5bDmFd05Xu6z4e0aiWQ=
```

How this could be decrypted in Perl???

Comment: Deja Vu. Not so long ago I had seen a question: Encrypt in PHP, Decrypt in Python.

Comment: I have been trying to use Crypt::CBC and Crypt::OpenSSL::AES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you'll need a combination of [MIME::Base64](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME%3a%3aBase64) and [MCrypt](https://metacpan.org/module/Mcrypt).

Comment: Many thanks Dave. I am getting this error.  Can't locate Mcrypt.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/xampp/perl/site/lib/ C:/xampp/perl/lib C:/xampp/perl/site/lib . C:/xampp/apache) at C:/xampp/htdocs/sites/test/hello.pl line 5. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/xampp/htdocs/sites/test/hello.pl line 5. ,

Comment: When I copy Mcrypt.pm file in the these directories and reload the page, I get  Can't locate loadable object for module Crypt::Rijndael in @INC (@INC contains: C:/xampp/perl/site/lib/ C:/xampp/perl/lib C:/xampp/perl/site/lib . C:/xampp/apache) at C:/xampp/htdocs/sites/test/hello.pl line 5 Compilation failed in require at C:/xampp/htdocs/sites/test/hello.pl line 5. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/xampp/htdocs/sites/test/hello.pl line 5. ,

Comment: Yes, you'll need to install it properly (via the "cpan" / "cpanm" commands, usually; Google for 'install cpan module' for details). Don't just try to manually copy the files around it won't work.

Comment: presh, do not send people off to Google. Instead, put a useful link to a canonical resource. Fitting example: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Answer (score 1):

There is a package in cpan .. MCrypt

http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MCrypt

Check this out