# how solve this Missing right curly or square bracket in  base.pm perl

Tags: perl

```
use DateTime::Format::RFC3339;

my $format = DateTime::Format::RFC3339->new();
my $dt = $format->parse_datetime('1996-08-29T00:00:00.0000Z');
say $dt->strftime('%d-%b-%Y');  # 29-Aug-1996
```

when i run this scripts I get the error below:

> Missing right curly or square bracket at
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/DateTime/Locale/Base.pm
>   line 1, at end of line syntax error at
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/DateTime/Locale/Base.pm
>   line 1, at EOF

---

Besides `base.pm` was copied from cpan http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DROLSKY/DateTime-Locale-0.45/lib/DateTime/Locale/Base.pm

Comment: I wonder what do you mean by `copied`? Didn't you just install DateTime::Locale?

Comment: May be an old version problem, try updating DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

The [current version of DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime) is 0.75,
[DateTime-Format-RFC3339](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-RFC3339) is 1.0.5.

To install the modules properly, see [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module).

Answer (score -2):

I use DateTime for the more complex stuff.  For simple parse/format I do this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Date::Parse;
use Date::Format;

my $dt = str2time('1996-08-29T00:00:00.0000Z');
print time2str('%d-%b-%Y', $dt);
```

Comment: @downvoter - Does the guy actually want to debug DateTime or format a date?

Comment: What the OP wants is in this question's subject. But think through what you wrote: how does recommending a different module help if the OP has weird ideas about deploying them? Have a guess what happens next. – A good answer should take into account the problem at hand.