# Error "Can't locate version.pm in @INC" when I call my DBI module

Tags: perl, cpan

I have installed DBI and DBD module in my computer, but when I execute the perl script, errors like "Can't locate version.pm in @INC" occurs. Is there something wrong with my DBD ?or Is there some dependency need to be installed?

My OS is Redhat Linux, perl version 5.8.8, which satisfies the requirements of DBD installation.

Here is what the @INC contains:

```
/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8

locate version returns:
/opt/app/ora11g/product/11.2.0/client_1/perl/lib/5.10.0/version.pm
```

Comment: What is the OS and perl installation?  Have checked your lib path?  `perl -le 'print foreach @INC'`

Comment: And what does `locate version.pm` return?

Comment: I have added the result, maybe that is the point but how to modify?

Comment: Have you tried installing version??

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Answer (score 5):

```
corelist version

version was first released with perl v5.9.0
```

Since your version of perl is older than perl<sup>**5.9.0**</sup> you may have to install `version.pm` manually.

Comment: my perl version is 5.8.8, which version of version.pm is suitable to install?

Comment: I guess you are trying to install the module manually. Please use `cpan` or `cpanm` to install the module. Install the latest version: `0.99`.

Comment: I had the same problem upgrading bugzilla 4.4.1 to 4.4.10 on EL7 with perl 5.16.3   . To correct the issue I ran:  yum -y install 'perl(version)' , and the problem went away

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is something wrong with your Perl installation.

`version` has been a core module since Perl v5.9.0 and it is used by only a few modules, not including DBI

Which package is failing with this error? The message will tell you which file is using `version`. You can either do without this package or install a newer version of Perl