# perl library path

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I need to retrieve the path where the perl libraries Statistics and Distributions are located. The path is necessary to run the script. I'm on a computer cluster. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: We're here to help. Please give us your username and password and the name or IP address of a machine on your cluster. One of us will be happy to poke around and see where the libraries can be found. [Edit: smiley face]

Comment: yes, of course...just getting fired tomorrow!

Comment: Your question (as of know) is too vague. I understand it as: a script of yours tries to load some modules, and fails. Please edit the question to add the error line "can't locate Statistics/Distributions.pm in @INC" (taken from your comment below).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer assumes that the module is in fact installed, but not in a place that `perl` is looking for.

Generally, the Perl module `Statistics::Distributions` will be contained in a file called `Statistics/Distributions.pm`. On Linux and similar systems, one can search for these files quickly with the `locate` command:

```
locate Statistics/Distributions.pm
```

If it is installed, `locate` will spit out a line similar to

```
/opt/my_perl/lib/Statistics/Distributions.pm
```

You can then instruct the `perl` interpreter to look in this path, too, in various ways. One is to define the environment variable `PERL5LIB`, i.e. from `bash`:

```
prompt> PERL5LIB=/opt/my_perl/lib/ ./myscript.pl
```

Or you can use the `perl -I` switch:

```
prompt> perl -I/opt/my_perl/lib/ ./myscript.pl
```

Or you can modify the script to `use lib`; there is more than one way to do it ;-)

Answer (score 5):

`perldoc -m Your::Module` - displays source of module

`perldoc -l Your::Module` - display path to library if it's installed and found in PERL5LIB, -I, @INC, etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean you need the path of a module you're using in a program, that's stored in `%INC`:

```
$ perl -MLWP::Simple -le 'print $INC{"LWP/Simple.pm"}'
/usr/share/perl5/LWP/Simple.pm
```

Comment: Since the script was not written by me I'm reporting the comment reported:Dependency: library Statistics::Distributions (please modify the first  line of the script to set the path to the library location

Comment: @Eleonora Lusito, To your question, add the **exact** error message and demonstrate what triggers its appearance.

Comment: ok, trying to run the script, the error appearing is: can't locate Statistics/Distributions.pm in @INC

Comment: sorry memowe, I don' t understand your question.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to run `cpan Statistics::Distributions` to install the module. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865

Comment: Use `@ikegami` when you reply to ikegami to notify him of your comment. Otherwise, only the person who wrote the answer or question to which you are replying gets notified.

Answer (score 1):

"`Can't locate XXX in @INC`" usually indicates the module isn't installed. Have you installed [Statistics::Distributions](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Statistics%3a%3aDistributions)?

```
cpan Statistics::Distributions
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't know if it is installed since I'm not cluster admin.

Comment: Let me put it differently: It's not installed, at least not somewhere Perl has been told to find it. So get it installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble and it can be fixed both ways:

1) by running the command

```sh
perl -I/blabla/folder_your_module_is_installed/blib/lib/ ./script.pl
```

for dummies like me, it is important to note that the end of the path is `lib/`, not `lib/Other_folder/`. Because there are more folders after it.

2) inside the script you can write:

```perl
use lib 'blabla/folder_your_module_is_installed/blib/lib/';
```

save and run perl scripit.pl