# Dynamic Shared Library error when creating exe from cx_freeze

Tags: bash, python-3.x, opencv, cx-freeze

I have a python file using OpenCV library.I want this in as an executable file.

Came across this [cx_freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/)

Example:

ABC.py(file using opencv library)

Content of setup.py is given below

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(  name = "ABC",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Testing",
        executables = [Executable("ABC.py")],
)
```

I ran this command in the terminal

```
python setup.py install
```

It is stopping after showing this error message

```
copying /Users/name/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so -> build/exe.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.6/lib/cv2.so
copying /Users/name/.virtualenvs/test/bin/../lib/libopencv_reg.3.3.dylib -> build/exe.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.6/libopencv_reg.3.3.dylib
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/name/.virtualenvs/test/bin/../lib/libopencv_reg.3.3.dylib'
```

I know from the error message that libopencv_reg.3.3.dylib is not found.

I'm running this on a python virtual environment.
This is my bash_profile content

```
#Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

#export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

# Virtualenv/VirtualenvWrapper
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
#export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
#export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
#export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
#export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'
```

I'm confused please help me out fix this.
Guidance would really be helpful, if this question can be posted else where let me know rather than down voting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared the same on OpenCV forum

here's the response I got [there](http://answers.opencv.org/question/177847/libopencv_reg33dylib/)

Looks like we have build OpenCV in such a way that other shared objects(.so) files are not dependent.

Answer (score 0):

can you search your filesystem for the missing file?  When you find it you can set PERL5LIB or use -I switch to set the location into the perl path

[perl library path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320543/perl-library-path)