# Gradle not showing highlighted warnings

Tags: gradle, logging, warnings

I can't make Gradle show (highlighted) warnings that I emit from my build script using

```
logger.warn("something something")
```

The line is emitted plain, like any other log line, it does not have a WARN next to it, I was expecting some colour with `--console=rich`, nothing.

Also, the warning is simply emitted at the respective place in the log.
**I would like them emitted there but also at the end, or at least something at the end to indicate there were warnings. Supposedly `--warning-mode=summary` is for this but doesn't have any effect.**

I tried all possible combinations like:

```
gradle --warning-mode=summary build
gradle build --warning-mode=all
gradle build --warning-mode all
gradle build -Dorg.gradle.warning.mode=all --console=rich --info
etc
```

I tried gradle 5.2 and 5.4.1. No warnings!

Answer (score 2):

`warn` messages from the `logger` always look like that. They are visible by default; while `info` messages are only shown when using `--info` flag (or something more verbose).

Actually the `logger` is based on slf4j; but then it is up to Gradle to set the logging format (and they chose not to show the log level, nor the timestamp etc.)

When calling `logger.warn(..)`, that resolves to `project.logger`. See the reference for [Project.getLogger()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getLogger--) , and for the [Logger](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/logging/Logger.html) .

---

One way to show colored output (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516693/gradle-color-output)) is by using Gradle internal API like

```
import org.gradle.internal.logging.text.StyledTextOutput;
import org.gradle.internal.logging.text.StyledTextOutputFactory;
def out = services.get(StyledTextOutputFactory).create("my-factory")
out.withStyle(StyledTextOutput.Style.FailureHeader).println('Failure message')
out.withStyle(StyledTextOutput.Style.Success).println('Success message')
```

---

A dirty (and trivial) way to show "WARN" in your messages is obviously to use `logger.warn('WARN: message')`.

---

Finally, instead of printing warnings, tasks can be interrupted by throwing exceptions, so that Gradle will stop the build and show what went wrong, eg. when running `gradle taskA` with:

```
task taskB {
  doLast{
    throw new Exception("error here")
  }
}

task taskA {
  dependsOn taskB
}
```

Comment: OK. Exceptions is what I moved away from, because I have a non-fatal use-case but that is really important to highlight to the user. Given that `StyledTextOutput` is internal API (and old posts too, and I don't see a preset for warnings), I will rest with the "dirty and trivial" solution that I had already implement

Comment: But the question is not so much about the colours, what's more important is the ability to show a summary at the end. Why doesn't **--warning-mode=summary** work? Gradle seems to be very good at outputting `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0` warning, it should somehow facilitate user warnings also?