# markdown: HTML block level tags wrapped by <p>

Tags: perl, markdown

I'm using markdown.pl downloaded from directly from Darring Fireball to translate .md files into html.

I start the file with some block level html, then followed by markdown syntax

```
<div class="header">title</div>

# header
```

markdown keeps wrap the `<div>` class with `<p>` tags, producing:

```
<p><div class="header">title</div></p>
<h1>header</h1>
```

If I start the file with a newline, before the html block level tag, an empty

will be produced

```
<p></p>
<div class="header">title</div>
<h1>header</h1>
```

I want to know how to stop markdown from wrapping my block-level HTML tags with `<p>`s.

Answer (score 1):

That code is not maintained because Gruber don't care. [¹](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/responsible-open-source-code-parenting.html) [²](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/10/the-future-of-markdown.html)

Use [Text-Markdown Markdown.pl](http://p3rl.org/Markdown.pl) instead, it works like you expect it to.

Comment: Hi thanks for updating me. I'm quiet new to programming world, so I'm a little confused to how to use this new version. I downloaded the tar.gz file, extracted it, and tried to run it from command line with `perl script/Markdown.pl myFile.md`, but I get following error: `Can't locate Text/Markdown.pm in @INC at script/Markdown.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script/Markdown.pl line 4.` How do I run the script to translate?

Comment: You must tell Perl where to find the library files, run `perl -Ilib …` from the same unpacked base directory; or better yet, install the distribution, so it can figure it out without you needing to tell. – From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=frequent): [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Comment: I finally got the module working, but it's not solving my problem. [This](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Text-Markdown-1.000031/lib/Text/Markdown.pm#OPTIONS) is still wrapping the first line of html tags in <p>s.

Comment: Remove the [BOM](http://enwp.org/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) at the beginning of the file. A good editor certainly has an option for that.