# How to install the cpan modules

Tags: perl, cpan

How to install the perl facebook API cpan modules and dependencies in a single command

```
   www::Facebook:api
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo cpan WWW::Facebook::API
```

(case-sensitive!)

Answer (score 0):

[Install Cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/module/App::cpanminus) in the way that pleased you, then you can simply type :

```
cpanm WWW::Facebook::API
```

See also [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module) and the [cpan.org introduction to installing Perl Modules](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).