# Can't locate BMP.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I am trying to run a third-party script, but I get this error. I suppose I need to install a Perl module `BMP.pm` but is it part of some package? I am on Ubuntu.

```
aptitude search bmp | grep perl
```

yields no suitable packages.

UPDATE

I know my question is not very detailed. But this is because I am new to perl, I just happened to run some program and wanted to find out something that was not easy to find using google. When the error message said "cannot locate Gd.pm" I was able to find that I can just "aptitude install libgd-perl", but BMP is not so easy to find, I know this must be intuitive and obvious, but not for me. That's why I ask for some help. You already been helpful pointing out that I must find the module require line. Here it is:

```
use GD;
use Image::BMP;
use Image::Size;
use File::Copy;
use File::Spec;
```

Sorry I have no idea what is CPAN. It seems to be important part of perl, but I never heared this acronym before until now.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of BMP.pm . Look at http://search.cpan.org/search?query=bmp and see the module you need. Then try searching on your ubuntu system the package.

Comment: It might help you if you look to see what perl modules the script requires by looking at the top of the script or maybe by greping for 'use'.  Just looking at CPAN, there's a lot of BMP.pm modules listed

Comment: `Can't locate BMP.pm in @INC` this message get us the **full name** of the module. In CPAN there is not such module or I was looking bad, nevertheless BMP.pm you should find where located the script.

Comment: *"My gas boiler isn't working, and the instructions say my house needs to be five feet higher. Please help"*. It would be useful to see the error messages that you get that tell you `BMP.pm` is missing, and to know something about the script you are trying to run.

Comment: Why on earth is this question getting upvotes?

Comment: With my very best intentions, because of your *"Sorry I have no idea what is CPAN"*, I have to recommend that your question be closed, on the grounds that *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"*. Stack Overflow is a place to find help when you already have most of the answer, not a quick alternative to learning a language.

Comment: [What is CPAN?](http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#What_is_CPAN)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're missing the Image::BMP perl module.  You can install that from CPAN, a resource containing public repositories of perl modules.  There are many ways to do it, and this link will give you a few ideas:

http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html

If you have admin rights to the computer you're working on (my hunch is yes), then probably installing the module system wide is the easiest.  You can install it from the commandline with:

`sudo cpan -i Image::BMP`

If it's the first time running cpan (my hunch is yes!), then you might have to go through a few CPAN setup steps, but it is well written and easy to navigate.

You might also double check that you have the rest of the required modules, as I think that at least GD is not a standard module in the core perl package.  You can quickly check to see if you have the module installed from the commandline like so:

`perl -MGD -e '1'`

or

`perl -MImage::Size -e '1'`

If you get no result, the module is already installed and perl located it.  If you get an error, then you probably need to install the module from CPAN as above.

Comment: `sudo cpan` runs too much code as root; limit it by just using `cpan` and configuring it to use sudo for the installation step.

Answer (score 1):

Note that given the code you show, I strongly suspect Image/ was in the error message; please try to copy error messages literally when you ask questions.

In general, to find which ubuntu package has a perl module, go to packages.ubuntu.com and search for packages containing files that end e.g. Image/BMP.pm.  In this case, there does not seem to be an ubuntu package, so you are stuck with installing it from CPAN.

Start with:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

then:

```
cpan Image::BMP
```

cpan will ask a number of configuration questions the first time around.