# "Can't locate DateTime.pm" error in perl

Tags: perl

while running script i am getting below error:

```
Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/ve
```

my code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use DateTime;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:mysql:dbname=agilefant-test",
   "agilefant-test",
    "Agilefant-test",
    { RaiseError => 1 },
) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $datestring = strftime "%Y %m %d %X", gmtime;
my $fourteen_days_from_now = $datestring->add(days =>14);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("Insert into backlogs (backlogtype, id, description, name, backlogSize, baselineLoad, endDate, readonlyToken, startDate, rank, status, parent_id)
values ('Project' , '200', 'Sanchit Testing', 'Maintenance agilefant', NULL, NULL, ('$fourteen_days_from_now'), NULL, ('$datestring'), NULL, NULL, '34')");
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
$sth->finish();
```

As from previous questions it different coz i cant upgrade my system as i dont have rights and also and i want to set End Date as after 14 days from current date. So need help for that also.

Comment: So [install](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) it. (You might want to [upgrade](http://perlbrew.pl/) from Perl 5.8 to one that is supported while you're at it. Perl 5.18 is the current stable, you're 5 major versions behind.)

Comment: any other option because i cant upgrade it

Comment: upgrading perl would not get you DateTime; DateTime is not included with the perl core, you must install it from CPAN (or whatever packaging system your os provides, which likely has it available)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a system which you can't apply upgrades to, you should consider [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/).
It handles all perl administration locally for the current user.
i.e. you don't need admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Time::Piece`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3a%3aPiece) and [`Time::Seconds`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3a%3aSeconds) to add days to a date, and it also has the POSIX `strftime`. Also, they are core modules in Perl since v5.9.5.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $t = localtime;
$t += ONE_DAY * 14;
print $t->strftime('%Y %m %d %X');
```

Comment: @ysth, Suprisingly, this actually works because Time::Piece overrides `localtime` to return an object with overloaded operators.

Comment: @ikegami You're right, there's apparently more that goes on under the hood than meets the eye. Is there a good test case for date math to try this out?

Comment: ah, never mind, then. ssorry

Comment: For me POSIX strftime is working okay and related to Datetime.pm or Time.pm related not working on my system and i dont have permission to upgrade. I used perl -MPOSIX -e '$t = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime(time() + 14 * 24 * 3600); print $t'. this is also have problem as Not all days have 24*3600 seconds. I am finding any other solution which gives me exact 14 days from todays date in end date??

Comment: @sammy, You don't need any special permissions to install modules.

Comment: @ikegami I have tried to install by different suggestions but getting error

Comment: @sammy Did you follow the link to the question above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module

Comment: Saying naught but "getting error" in a comment is a not good way to get help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to install the missing module.

If you can't install it, according your code, maybe you just want get the date string of 14 days after today? You can compute it by your self with **time**.

just try this:

```
perl -MPOSIX -e '$t = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime(time() + 14 * 24 * 3600); print $t'
```

Comment: with the solution you provided i am getting only one date after if today 11-12 then i get 12-12....I want 14 days after.....

Comment: Not all days have 24*3600 seconds. In addition to giving the date 14 days from now as desired, your code can give the date 13 days from now, and it can give the date 15 days from now.

Comment: For me POSIX strftime is working okay and related to Datetime.pm or Time.pm related not working on my system and i dont have permission to upgrade. I used perl -MPOSIX -e '$t = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime(time() + 14 * 24 * 3600); print $t'. this is also have problem as Not all days have 24*3600 seconds. I am finding any other solution which gives me exact 14 days from todays date in end date??