# How can I install LWP::Protocol::https?

Tags: perl, lwp

I created a Perl script to run an https task.  When I run it I get the error `LWP::Protocol::https` not installed.

I cannot figure out, or find a tutorial or command on how exactly to install `LWP::Protocol::http`. Anyone have any idea how to install it? Installing `LWP` was quite easy.

I have installed `LWP` and installed `Crypt-SSLeay`, however I still get the error.  Here is my code:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;


# set custom HTTP request header fields

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(PUT => "https://thesite.com");

$req->header('Authorization' => 'myauth');
$req->header('Accept' => 'JSON:Application/JSON');
$req->header('Content-Type' => 'JSON:Application/JSON');
$req->header('Host' => 'api.thesite.com');

$req->content('Text' => 'thetext');



my $resp = $ua->request($req);
if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
    print "Received reply: $message\n";
}
else {
    print "HTTP POST error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print "HTTP POST error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
}
```

Comment: If the error tells you `LWP::Protocol::https` is not installed, install it.

Comment: Oh geesh.  It's been a bad day.  I need to edit this question.  I got so caught up, I didn't as the right thing...

Comment: The question was supposed to be... HOW do I install it.  I can't seem to find that information anywhere.

Comment: `cpan` then `install LWP::Protocol::https` or `install Bundle::LWP`

Comment: See: [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Comment: Man, I thought I tried that.  Ok, very good.  It is installing now.  Thanks so much for the quick help!!

Answer (score 24):

`sudo yum install perl-LWP-Protocol-https` fixed issue for me.

Answer (score 12):

Running `sudo cpan install LWP::Protocol::https` fixed this for me.

Comment: `sudo perl -MCPAN -we 'install "LWP::Protocol::https"'` didn't worked because some test failed, and your command worked. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Note that the "install" in that command is a no-op. Just `cpan LWP::Protocol::https` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, `LWP` came with HTTPS support. Then, [in 6.02 (in 2011)](https://metacpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/changes), they unbundled the `LWP::Protocol::https`. If your program was set up on an ancient system and you are upgraded, this change can trip you up.

Since Perl does not have SSL support out of the box, it didn't make sense to have a protocol helper that was missing what it needs (and remember HTTPS everywhere wasn't quite as prevalent then). As a separate module, it's easier to get everything set up.

Now, here's the trick. `LWP::Protocol::https` needs `IO::Socket::SSL` which needs [Net::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay) which needs [openssl](https://www.openssl.org). How you install that is up to you, and if your platform has a ready-to-go package, that might be best (because if you know you don't want that, you're unlikely to ask your question).

If you want to do the whole chain yourself, start with [openssl](https://www.openssl.org). Once that's sorted, you can install the module you need and the rest of the pre-requisites will take care of themselves:

```
# ... install openssl, set env vars if in a nonstandard location
% cpan LWP::Protocol::https
```

---

As a side note, older Perl practices didn't include using all the modules you knew you depended on. In this case, you formerly didn't declare a dependency on `LWP::Protocol::https` because you knew it came with `LWP`. Now it's much better to explicitly declare every thing you need even if you know some modules come in the same distribution. Maybe some time in the future they'll be in different distributions.

Although I use `Mojo::UserAgent` for all this now, I'd add the explicit dependency even though `LWP` takes care of it all internally. This makes static analysis a bit easier:

```
use LWP;
use LWP::Protocol::https;
```

Comment: Is there a chance to install LWP 6.01 or earler (version before unbundling the LWP::Protocol::https from LWP distribution)?

Comment: libwww-perl-6.01 is still available for download: https://metacpan.org/release/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.01

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error:

> Can't locate LWP/Protocol/https.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/cxs /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 5) line 2.

You need to install `LWP::Protocol::https`, using for instance:

```
cpan LWP::Protocol::https
```