# Cloudstack api error: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at sign.pl line 12

Tags: perl, centos6

Error message: 
Can't locate XML/Twig.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/loc    al/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/li    b64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at sign.pl line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at sign.pl line 12.

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to a missing Perl module.

See this answer:
[What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Answer (score 0):

If you have SELinux running you may have to restore the security contexts for the web folder.
For instance:

> restorecon -Rv /var/www/html