# how to install cpan modules using system command - perl

Tags: perl

I am using **Windows operating system** and i have my running perl script.In my script `Path::Class::Rule` module i am using .

My script is not able to run, on some of the system, because the above mentioned module is not installed.So i need to add a logic for pre-setup which will check whether all the required module is installed on the system or not if not then install the module first then do rest of the processing.

I am trying to install the module using `system subroutine` but perl modules are not getting install.

Here is the code which i am using:

```
use warnings;
use Path::Class;
use Path::Class::Rule;
use Cwd qw();
use File::Path qw(make_path);
use File::Copy;
system ("ppm install Path::Class::Rule");
```

can any body help me out how to add the logic ?

Comment: In Windows - Go to the start and in the Run box type ppm then a window gets opened and their you can find perl modules . You have option mark for install for the perl modules at the top. After clicking that your modules get installed.I believe Path::Class:Rule is found and available in it.

Comment: i need to add the logic in my current perl script only . i dont want any manual interference.I have checked the mark for install option as you suggested but i can see it is disabled here. do am i have to update the perl?

Comment: Please, don't do that. You can ship the necessary files with your program. Best of all, rewrite your program to use [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec) and 
[`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Find) which are core modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:

```
use Path::Class::Rule;
...;
system ("ppm install Path::Class::Rule");
```

You're trying to `use` the module **before** installing it.

Try something like this:

```
BEGIN {
   eval { require Path::Class::Rule }
      or system("ppm install Path::Class::Rule");
}
use Path::Class::Rule;
```

Though personally I think a better idea is something like:

```
BEGIN {
   eval { require Path::Class::Rule }
      or die "Missing Path::Class::Rule. See README for installation instructions.\n";
}
use Path::Class::Rule;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is flawed -- your code should not check for missing modules (it will be done on each run).

You can install CPAN modules with following command

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install [MODULE]'
```

You could use **batch** or **cmd** installation file to install all required modules.

You could use *perl* **installation script** which will verify what modules are missing and install them.

**NOTE:** Your post is not clear if you refer to **install script** or not.

You need read documentation 'perl module installation'

[How to install CPAN modules](https://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html)

[How to install CPAN modules](https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_install_PERL_modules)

[What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Comment: Docker alpine gives
perl -MCPAN -e 'install File::Which'
Can't locate object method "install" via package "File::Which" at -e line 1.

Answer (score 0):

or use
perl -MCPAN -eshell

to use the install [module] from the command line