# Error running EasyApache

Tags: linux, perl, cpanel, whm

I am trying to run easyapache on my server and get the following error:

> !! Failed to install CPAN Perl module(s) Tie::IxHash Net::SSL
>   Date::Format B::Fathom Net::Ident Mail::Send B::LexInfo Devel::Symdump
>   BSD::Resource Inline Data::Flow Time::ParseDate IPC::Run3 Devel::Cover
>   !!

The idea is to add mbstring extension to my PHP.

Any idea of the problem or how to add this extension without run easyapache?

Answer (score 2):

Error message says it clearly, it failed to install some Perl modules. Try installing them like below.

```
$ cpan Tie::IxHash
```

See:

- [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)
- [A Guide to Installing Modules](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=128077)