# Can't locate File/Find/Rule.pm in @INC

Tags: linux, multithreading, perl, cpan

```
!#/usr/bin/perl -w  
use strict;  
use warnings;  
use File::Find::Rule;  
my $finder=File::Find::Rule->directory->in($directory);
```

Warning is

```
Can't locate File/Find/Rule.pm in @INC  
(@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at ./test.pl line 4.  
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./test.pl line 4.
```

Comment: Download the module.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module

Answer (score 2):

`File::Find::Rule` module is not install in your system where you are executing your Perl script. Install that module.

Other things in your code is shebang line start with `#!` not with `!#`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

Use `use warnings;` or `-w`, not both.

Comment: How can I install File::Find::Rule module ?

Comment: There are several question on SO about how to install module. Please search. Read this -> http://perlmaven.com/how-to-install-a-perl-module-from-cpan and this -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/65865/4248931