# MP3::Tag - not working

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to write a small program in perl which uses the MP3::Tag module.
The program doesn't execute and gives me:

```
Can't locate MP3/Tag.pm in @INC (you may need to install the MP3::Tag module) (@INC contains: ... .) at mp3Editor.pl line 3.
```

where line 3 is: `use MP3::Tag;`

So then I try the command: `cpan MP3::Tag`

but I get: `Warning: Cannot install MP3::Tag, don't know what it is.`

I've downloaded the module from CPAN's website, however I can't seem to get it working. What must I do to get **MP3::Tag** module working on my system? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**  `env | grep -i perl` produces:

```
PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base "/home/bronson/perl5"
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/home/bronson/perl5
```

Comment: Try using [`cpanm`](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus) instead, it is a far more user friendly CPAN client than `cpan`.

Comment: `cpanm` seems to have at least done something. I still get the same issue when trying to run the program itself though.

Comment: Then you probably have multiple copies of Perl installed. Your program is using one, and cpanm is installing to another. cpanm will use whatever Perl is in your PATH, check with `which perl` and check that against your `#!` line at the top of your program.

Comment: They are both usr/bin/perl . But I think you're right. I noticed I have a perl5 with mp3 stuff in it located in my documents somewhere. How could I change this or move it?

Comment: That's odd. Check `which cpanm` and see if that's coming from somewhere odd. I'd also check `env | grep -i perl` to see if any environment variables affecting installation are set.

Comment: `which cpanm` is `usr/bin/cpanm` ... `env | grep -i perl` is my perl5 in some random documents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105748/discussion-between-schwern-and-oxenmeat).

Comment: You might not have the rep for chat. All that perl stuff in your environment is likely what is causing the problem. If you the output of `env | grep -i perl` to your question then people might be able to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `cpan` client is misconfigured, it doesn't seem to have a proper list of CPAN modules.  [`cpanm`](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus) is a more user friendly CPAN client than `cpan`, I recommend using it instead.

If a freshly installed `cpanm` installs the module but you're still getting the error, and if `which perl` and the Perl in your `#!` line are the same, then your modules are probably getting installed outside the standard Perl library locations.  There's a few ways this could happen, the first is to check for environment variables affecting your installation.  `env | grep -i perl` is a good start.  Things like `PERL_MB_OPT` and `PERL_MM_OPT` will alter how `cpan` and `cpanm` call the Build.PL and Makefile.PL installers.

If `PERL_M*_OPT` are set then there should be a corresponding `PERL5LIB` to tell Perl to look in the non-standard location for those modules.

This is usually done to allow non-root users to install modules into their home directory.

In your case you seem to have `PERL_M*_OPT` set but no `PERL5LIB`.  You'll need to set `PERL5LIB` to where ever the modules got installed, probably `/home/bronson/perl5/lib/perl5/`.

---

This can all get a bit hairy.  There's two tools to make this easier.

First is [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/).  It installs Perl in your home directory and configures everything for you.  It can even support multiple versions.  This is the simplest and recommended way to develop Perl.  It gives you full control over the Perl installation, you're not tied to what the system has installed.

The other is to use [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) to manage your Perl environment.  It will help you set Perl environment variables to install Perl modules to your home directory and use them.  You might have a mangled version of that right now.