# XML::Twig fails to install on mac terminal

Tags: macos, perl, module, installation, xml-twig

I am trying to install twig on mac terminal but it seems to have a lot of error as follows:

```
Admins-MBP:~ admin$ cpan install XML::Twig
    CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.34)
    Reading '/Users/admin/.cpan/Metadata'
      Database was generated on Mon, 15 Aug 2016 09:17:02 GMT
    CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9725)
    Warning: You are not allowed to write into directory "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors".




        I'll continue, but if you encounter problems, they may be due
        to insufficient permissions.
    CPAN: HTTP::Tiny loaded ok (v0.017)
    Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
    http://cpan.mirrors.uk2.net/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    Error downloading with HTTP::Tiny: Error: Could not open temporary file /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123482202692 for downloading: Permission denied
     at /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/5.16.0/CPAN/HTTP/Client.pm line 41.


    Trying with
        /usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
    to get
        http://cpan.mirrors.uk2.net/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    sh: /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123: Permission denied

        Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://cpan.mirrors.uk2.net/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123"")
        returned status 1 (wstat 256)
    Warning: expected file [/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123] doesn't exist
        Warning: no success downloading '/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123'. Giving up on it.
    Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
    http://www.cpan.dk/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    Error downloading with HTTP::Tiny: Error: Could not open temporary file /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp221231577050846 for downloading: Permission denied
     at /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/5.16.0/CPAN/HTTP/Client.pm line 41.


    Trying with
        /usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
    to get
        http://www.cpan.dk/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    sh: /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123: Permission denied

        Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://www.cpan.dk/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123"")
        returned status 1 (wstat 256)
    Warning: expected file [/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123] doesn't exist
        Warning: no success downloading '/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123'. Giving up on it.
    Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
    http://mirror.met.hu/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    Error downloading with HTTP::Tiny: Error: Could not open temporary file /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123669027792 for downloading: Permission denied
     at /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/5.16.0/CPAN/HTTP/Client.pm line 41.


    Trying with
        /usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
    to get
        http://mirror.met.hu/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    sh: /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123: Permission denied

        Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://mirror.met.hu/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123"")
        returned status 1 (wstat 256)
    Warning: expected file [/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123] doesn't exist
        Warning: no success downloading '/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123'. Giving up on it.
    Warning: You are not allowed to write into directory "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors".
        I'll continue, but if you encounter problems, they may be due
        to insufficient permissions.

    Trying with
        /usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
    to get
        http://cpan.mirrors.uk2.net/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    sh: /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123: Permission denied

        Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://cpan.mirrors.uk2.net/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123"")
        returned status 1 (wstat 256)
    Warning: expected file [/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123] doesn't exist

    Trying with
        /usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
    to get
        http://www.cpan.dk/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    sh: /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123: Permission denied

        Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://www.cpan.dk/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123"")
        returned status 1 (wstat 256)
    Warning: expected file [/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123] doesn't exist

    Trying with
        /usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
    to get
        http://mirror.met.hu/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    sh: /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123: Permission denied

        Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://mirror.met.hu/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123"")
        returned status 1 (wstat 256)
    Warning: expected file [/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123] doesn't exist
        Warning: no success downloading '/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123'. Giving up on it.
    Warning: You are not allowed to write into directory "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors".
        I'll continue, but if you encounter problems, they may be due
        to insufficient permissions.
    No external ftp command available

    Warning: You are not allowed to write into directory "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors".
        I'll continue, but if you encounter problems, they may be due
        to insufficient permissions.
    Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
    http://cpan.mirrors.uk2.net/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    Error downloading with HTTP::Tiny: Error: Could not open temporary file /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp221231089200351 for downloading: Permission denied
     at /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/5.16.0/CPAN/HTTP/Client.pm line 41.


    Trying with
        /usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
    to get
        http://cpan.mirrors.uk2.net/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    sh: /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123: Permission denied

        Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://cpan.mirrors.uk2.net/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123"")
        returned status 1 (wstat 256)
    Warning: expected file [/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123] doesn't exist
        Warning: no success downloading '/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123'. Giving up on it.
    Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
    http://www.cpan.dk/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    Error downloading with HTTP::Tiny: Error: Could not open temporary file /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp221231652346630 for downloading: Permission denied
     at /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/5.16.0/CPAN/HTTP/Client.pm line 41.


    Trying with
        /usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
    to get
        http://www.cpan.dk/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    sh: /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123: Permission denied

        Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://www.cpan.dk/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123"")
        returned status 1 (wstat 256)
    Warning: expected file [/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123] doesn't exist
        Warning: no success downloading '/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123'. Giving up on it.
    Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
    http://mirror.met.hu/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
    Error downloading with HTTP::Tiny: Error: Could not open temporary file /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123742645488 for downloading: Permission denied
     at /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/5.16.0/CPAN/HTTP/Client.pm line 41.





Trying with
    /usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
to get
    http://mirror.met.hu/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
sh: /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123: Permission denied
```

Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://mirror.met.hu/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123"")
        returned status 1 (wstat 256)
    Warning: expected file [/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123] doesn't exist
        Warning: no success downloading '/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123'. Giving up on it.
    Warning: You are not allowed to write into directory "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors".
        I'll continue, but if you encounter problems, they may be due
        to insufficient permissions.

```
Trying with
    /usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
to get
    http://cpan.mirrors.uk2.net/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
sh: /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123: Permission denied

    Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://cpan.mirrors.uk2.net/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123"")
    returned status 1 (wstat 256)
Warning: expected file [/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123] doesn't exist

Trying with
    /usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
to get
    http://www.cpan.dk/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
sh: /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123: Permission denied

    Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://www.cpan.dk/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123"")
    returned status 1 (wstat 256)
Warning: expected file [/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123] doesn't exist

Trying with
    /usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
to get
    http://mirror.met.hu/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
sh: /Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123: Permission denied

    Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://mirror.met.hu/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123"")
    returned status 1 (wstat 256)
Warning: expected file [/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123] doesn't exist
    Warning: no success downloading '/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22123'. Giving up on it.
Warning: You are not allowed to write into directory "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors".
    I'll continue, but if you encounter problems, they may be due
    to insufficient permissions.
Warning: You are not allowed to write into directory "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors".
    I'll continue, but if you encounter problems, they may be due
    to insufficient permissions.
Warning: You are not allowed to write into directory "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors".
    I'll continue, but if you encounter problems, they may be due
    to insufficient permissions.
No external ftp command available

Please check, if the URLs I found in your configuration file
(http://cpan.mirrors.uk2.net/, http://www.cpan.dk/,
http://mirror.met.hu/CPAN/) are valid. The urllist can be edited. E.g. with
'o conf urllist push ftp://myurl/'

Could not fetch authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
```

Comment: `Warning: You are not allowed to write into directory "/Users/admin/.cpan/sources/authors".`

Comment: @Sobrique you are brilliant !! thanks, I install it by `sudo cpan install XML::Twig`how can i check whether it is working or not ?

Comment: @LearnerAlgorithm: Part of the skill of programming is learning to read the error message :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think is better not to install that module in your system perl. Try [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) and install your own perl (and handle many diferent perls if you need it).

Then, switch easily to the proper perl, and customize it with the required modules (with cpan or [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus)).

Comment: my problem actually is not this , look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607730/how-can-i-parse-a-xml-file I only need to run this script which after installing twig , I am facing problem again

Comment: @Miguel Prz my reputation is little to down vote !!! I do appreciate your answer, however i am still reading about it and i cannot like it because my reputation is little