# Can't locate Email/MIME.pm in @INC

Tags: mysql, apache, perl, bugzilla

while accessing bugzilla(http://localhost) on browser  i got the following error

```
Can't locate Email/MIME.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . lib/x86_64-linux-thread-***strong text***
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/MIME.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 20.
```

Thanks 
Surya

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have it installed using the command line:

*perl -e 'use Email::MIME'*

If it shows an error then try to install.