# deleting a particular column in csv which is enclosed with quotes

Tags: csv, unix, awk, sed

I have a csv file containing

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,"gg,hh,ii",j,k
```

I have been trying to use something like

```
awk -F ',' '{print $7}'
```

iam getting

```
"gg
```

but i need the result as

```
gg,hh,ii
```

can i get it done with a simple one line awk or sed command without any parsers

please help

Comment: For future reference: Aks unix questions on https://unix.stackexchange.com. For example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114754/extract-only-the-substring-after-double-quotes-grep answers your question. `echo 'a,b,c,d,e,f,"gg,hh,ii",j,k' | awk -F\" '{print $2}'`

Comment: `sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/'` i read this somewhere....can I modify it to delete a particular column alone?

Comment: @Ajit can you clarify your question? title says delete a column while expected output shows extracting a particular column

Comment: `sed 's/[^"]*"//; s/".*//'` would work for given sample, but that may not work for actual use case.. you might want to add more examples

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -we 'csv(in => shift, fragment => "col=7")' -- file.csv
```

See [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS) for details. The `fragment` option tells the`csv` function to only output the 7th column.

Comment: Can't locate Text/CSV_XS.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: @Ajit see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
awk -vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '{print $7}' file.csv
```

Use `FPAT` to define the content of the field instead of defining the field separator `FS` (with `-F` option).

For the `awk` man page:

> FPAT: A regular expression describing the contents of the fields in a record.  When set, gawk parses the input into fields, where the fields match the regular  expression,  instead of using the value of the FS variable as the field separator.

Comment: What if double quotes can also be included in the values with a backslash? `a,"b,c","d,\"e\",f"`

Comment: it is not working..I am getting only a blank line as output..@oliv