# Why doesn't perl find my installed SSH2 module?

Tags: perl, module, centos

So I am trying to run a perl script on my Centos machine. I have tried on Centos 5,6,7 with no success. Every time I run the script I get this:

```
Can't locate Net/SSH2.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .)
```

I have installed libssh2

```
Package libssh2-1.4.3-12.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

I have tried using cpan but no matter what I do it doesn't seem to work.
I just don't understand why perl isn't finding the module... Am I missing something?
If somebody could guide me to actually installing the SSH2 module because I have looked everywhere and nothing seems to work.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
When I try to install via cpan:

```
cpan[1]> install Net::SSH2
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
........................................................................DONE
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
Database was generated on Fri, 04 Jan 2019 22:17:03 GMT
HTTP::Date not available
.............
New CPAN.pm version (v2.22) available.
[Currently running version is v1.9800]
You might want to try
install CPAN
reload cpan
to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
the current session.


........................................Killed
```

Still getting the same error...

Comment: `install Net::SSH2`, not `install Net::SH2`. Though I'd see if it's available as a package in the centos repository before installing manually.

Comment: It's still now working... I don't think my cpan is working at all tbh, everything I type into it gives me the exact same response as you can see in my original post. I try googling but I can't find anything useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54054147/10874800), `libssh2` is the C library for SSH, whereas `Net::SSH2` is a Perl module.  Since `Net::SSH2` will be installed from source (which is what the `cpan` command does in the background), you will need to ensure that a few prerequisites are installed:

```
sudo yum install libssh2 libssh2-devel gcc
```

The `libssh2` package was added to this list for completeness.  The development package for `libssh2` (`libssh2-devel`) as well as `gcc` (a C compiler) are required, since the process of installing `Net::SSH2` from source requires a library to be built so that `Net::SSH2` can talk to `libssh2`.

When Perl modules are installed from source, the module's test suite is run by default to check that everything is ok before actually running the install step.  Hence, you will need to ensure that `perl-Test-Simple` is installed, since `Net::SSH2` uses this to run its tests:

```
sudo yum install perl-Test-Simple
```

I personally find it much easier to install Perl modules via [`cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) than `cpan`, thus I recommend installing it (it's available as a `yum` package):

```
sudo yum install perl-App-cpanminus
```

Now the installation of `Net::SSH2` should be as simple as:

```
cpanm Net::SSH2
```

If you want to install the module system-wide, then you will need to prefix the `cpanm` call with `sudo`:

```
sudo cpanm Net::SSH2
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

libssh is the C library for SSH. Net::SSH2 is a Perl module. They are different piece of software (although Net::SSH2 probably depends on libssh).

You need to install Net::SSH2.

See [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)