# How can I conversion Perl to create PDF files using XML/XSLT/XSL-FO

Tags: perl, apache-fop

I want to create pdf using XSLT, ApacheFOP use in PERL. Can anyone Help me?

```
    use 5.010;
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::ApacheFOP;
my $Fop = XML::ApacheFOP->new();
$Fop->fop( xml => "math.xml", xsl => "math.xsl", outfile => "temp.pdf" ) or die "cannot create pdf: " . $Fop->errstr;
```

Error showing in cmd line **can't locate XML/ApacheFOP.pm**

Comment: Looks like the perl module ```XML::ApacheFOP``` is not installed in your system.

Comment: @vinodk89 I have run for this command cpanm XML::ApacheFOP but not install this module. How can I install this Module?

Comment: The documentation [SETUP](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::ApacheFOP#SETUP) says you need java2 to be installed first before installing this module.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly because [XML::ApacheFOP](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::ApacheFOP) isn't installed. In a comment, you say that you have tried to install the module using `cpanm`, but it hasn't installed successfully. It would be useful to see the error messages that are displayed.

The [SETUP section of the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::ApacheFOP#SETUP) says that you will need [FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) installed before installing the module. If you're on Ubuntu, then that might be as easy as running `sudo apt-get install fop`. You should then try the module installation again. If it still fails, then ask a new question here, making sure to include the text of the error messages you get from `cpanm`.

Comment: Sir, if i am run the command "cpan install XML::ApacheFOP" in cmd prompt then last messasge showing "You can't run these tests unless JavaServer is running\n" Do you want to continue? (Y/n) if i m given the Y then show "Stopping: 'install' faild for 'Java'". I have already install Java my system.

Comment: And if i am another 2nd command "cpanm XML::ApacheFOP" then showing the message "Building and testing Java-4.7 ...." stop not continue.

Comment: The SETUP section that I linked to in my answer says that the FOP JavaServer needs to be running in order to use (or, obviously, test) the module. Just installing FOP isn't enough, you need to start it.

Comment: Sir, i have Download fop-2.4-bin.zip and extract the file after that move the file in C:\fop-2.4 but this avalon-framework-cvs-20020806.jar file missing in lib folder. how to add the classpath in System and afterthat run my perl script?

Comment: @Sandy: I'm afraid I know almost nothing about Java, FOP or developing on a Windows machine. I don't think I can be any more help here.

Comment: Sir, how to use this command =====/path/to/java -classpath \
/path/to/JavaServer.jar\
:/usr/local/xml-fop/build/fop.jar\
:/usr/local/xml-fop/lib/avalon-framework-cvs-20020806.jar\
:/usr/local/xml-fop/lib/batik.jar\
:/usr/local/xml-fop/lib/xalan-2.4.1.jar\
:/usr/local/xml-fop/lib/xercesImpl-2.2.1.jar \
com.zzo.javaserver.JavaServer ========= for the server is connect?

Comment: @Sandy: I know nothing about this area. I can't be any more help to you.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that your perl distro does not include `XML::ApacheFOP` module.

The module can be installed in several ways:

```
cpan install XML::ApacheFOP
```

or

```
cpanm XML::ApacheFOP
```

or

```
perl -MCPAN -e install XML::ApacheFOP
```

or download module extract it and run makefile.

It was pointed out that this particular module has **java** as pre-requisite and should be installed as well.

[How to install CPAN modules](https://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html)

[FAQ installing CPAN perl modules](https://dadamailproject.com/support/documentation-11_5_0/FAQ-installing_CPAN_Perl_modules.pod.html)

[How to install perl modules](https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_install_PERL_modules)

[What's the easiest way to install perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)